# I get Proguard Error with Navigation Component, How can I solve the problem?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, proguard, android-navigation

I turned on `Proguard` in my android application project.

And I published app and lots of crashes occurred. 99% crash free become 40% crash free...

And I get this critical exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: View android.widget.LinearLayout{ffb46cf V.E...... ......ID 0,0-720,1238} does not have a NavController set
        at b.m.B.a(Navigation.java:84)
        at com.example.view.main.fragment.k.a(WebViewFragment.kt:448)
```

I am using `Navigation Component` and most of the crashes happen at this line.

```
Navigation.findNavController(mView).navigate(R.id.action_aFragment_to_bFragment, bundle, null)
```

I added this in my `proguard-rules.pro`

```
-keep class * extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment{}
```

But Couldn't solve my problem. What should I do?